# Unable to remove legend box [python]

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I need to make this plot in python. I wish to remove my legend's border. However, when I tried the different solutions other posters made, they were unable to work with mine. Please help.

**This doesn't work:**

```
plt.legend({'z$\sim$0.35', 'z$\sim$0.1','z$\sim$1.55'})
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

---

```
plt.legend({'z$\sim$0.35', 'z$\sim$0.1','z$\sim$1.55'})
plt.legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.0)
```

---

```
plt.legend({'z$\sim$0.35', 'z$\sim$0.1','z$\sim$1.55'}, 'Box', 'off')
```

Additionally, when I plotted, I imported two different files and graphed them with a line and with circles respectively. How could I put a line or a circle within the legend key?

The plot:

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a minimal working example? Because using `plt.legend(frameon=False)` has never failed on me before...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very strange because the command :

```
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

Should work very well.
You can also try this command, to compare :

```
plt.legend(frameon=None)
```

You can also read the documentation on this page about [plt.legend](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html)

I scripted something as example to you :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.array([0,4,8,13])
y = np.array([0,1,2,3])

fig1, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.plot(x,y, label=u'test')
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)

ax2.plot(x,y, label=u'test2')
ax2.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=None)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to draw only one plot (without subplot)

```
plt.legend({'z$\sim$0.35', 'z$\sim$0.1','z$\sim$1.55'}, frameon=False)
```

It is enough one plt.legend. The second one rewrites the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure frameon = False is together with the positional argument in plt.legend(...) if you want to specify the position as well as remove the border. If these arguments are written separately or in sequential, there's an issue of overwriting and the desired effect may not be achieved.

Correct!
`plt.legend(loc="lower right", frameon=False)`

May not give desired effect when written like this!
`plt.legend(loc="lower right")` & `plt.legend(frameon=False)`